# How to show tags from json file using JQuery on an HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have problem reading the json file using JQuery. I don't have much knowledge about JQuery. I have following JSON file.

```js
[
  {'tag':'Hannover'},
  {'tag':'Berlin'},
  {'tag':'Munich'},
  {'tag':'Frankfurt'},
  {'tag':'Hamburg'}
]
```

and Javascript is as follows:

```html
<script>
  $.getJSON('tagData.json', function(data){
    $.each(data.items, function(key, val){
      $("<span name='tagList' class='tag label label-info'><span>"+val.tag+"</span><a><span class='remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white'></span></a></span>").appendTo('.list')
    });
  }); 

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $listGroup = $('.list') 
    $.each(myTags, function(){
      $("<span name='tagList' class='tag label label-info'><span>"+this.tag+"</span><a><span class='remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white'></span></a></span>").appendTo($listGroup);
    });

    $('#addButton').click(function() {
      var toAdd=$('input[name=checkbox]').val();
      var tag = "<span name='tagList' class='tag label label-info'><span>"+toAdd+"</span><a><span class='remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white'></span></a></span>"
      $(tag).appendTo('.list');
    });

    $('.list').on('click','span',function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
  });
</script>
```

and HTML code mentioned below:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="list">
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="text-center">
      <input type='text' name='checkbox'/>
      <br><br>
      <button id="addButton" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now what I want that it should display tags from the file and also If I want to add some more tags manually then I must be able to do so.

I have managed to add tags manually but when I try to add JSON file, it does not read it and also does not allow me to add manually. Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Below is the image which shows what I have managed to do so far.

Also the fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/amitJS/xncp92ho/)

Thank you.

Screenshot of the Tag suggestion page

[image]

Comment: Put the `$.getJSON` call *inside* `document.ready`. Currently you may be adding elements to `.list` before it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this jsFiddle link i have solved your problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/xncp92ho/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4skih', function(res){
$.each(res.data, function(key, val){
  $("<span name='tagList' class='tag label label-info'><span>"+val.tag+"</span><a><span class='remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white'></span></a></span>").appendTo('.list')
}); 

    $('#addButton').click(function() {
        var toAdd=$('input[name=checkbox]').val();
        var tag = "<span name='tagList' class='tag label label-info'><span>"+toAdd+"</span><a><span class='remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white'></span></a></span>"
        $(".list").append(tag);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Kaushik, thank you very much it is now working inside of my project. The only problem I am facing is that when I click on button to remove a tag, it removes all the tags. I tried many ways but as the tag and Id of all tags (button) is same, it just simply swipe away all the tags. Do you have any idea what could go wrong? I updated the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/xncp92ho/1/

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through `$.each(data.items, function` but your JSON file (and the data parameter) is actually just a simple array of objects, so this should just be `$.each(data, function`.